# Why is Maven is not able to resolve the version of plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to run the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=com.mycompany.api.tools:
```

I get the error when trying to run it. However, when I specify the version, it works fine:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate -Dfilter=com.mycompany.api.tools:
```

My local .m2/repository has only one version of the plugin. Why is maven not resolving the plugin version?

Comment: What's the question? When running Maven without a pom (like the generate goal of the maven-archetype-plugin), it's always better to use the fully qualified name to ensure that the preferred version is used.

Comment: The question is why the plugin version is not being resolved even though there is only one version of plugin on my local?

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Did you try removing the plugin from your .m2/repository and retry the command?